# tftp service is serving files but my Windows machine is not receiving them

Tags: tftp

I am running a `tftp` service on Linux and trying to transfer a file from Linux to a Windows 7 machine.

The error message I get is below:

[image: Snip of error]

Essentially, the Windows box responds with `"File not found. Connect request failed"` while in the logs on the Linux box it says `"Service (file) to (IP)(port)"`.

My `/etc/default/atftp` file looks as below:

```
USE_INETD=false
OPTIONS="--daemon --port 69 --retry-timeout 5 --maxthread 100 --verbose=5 /tftp"
```

Answer (score 0):

TFTP uses UDP port 69 only when establishing a file transfer, but the actual data trasnfer uses a randomly selected port similar to FTP. Check your Windows Firewall and see if the TFTP traffic is properly open. 
You can run a Wireshark traffic capture at i.e. Windows PC and see what's really going on at packet level.